# Rational points on circle

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

I need help for the following questions. Give the necessary and sufficient condition for $r$ such that the circle $x^{2}+y^{2}=r^{2}$ passes the rational points. I know the obvious sufficient condition is that $r\in\mathbb{Q}$. But I can't come up to necessary condition. regs,

Comment: What do you mean by "passes the rational points?"

Comment: Example for an irrational radius:  $r=\surd p$, with prime $p\equiv1\pmod4$ (for example $r=\surd 5$) there is a rational point  which is essentially unique (except for sign, and interchanging co-ordinates).

Comment: "passes the rational points" means for example this circle passes (r,0) where r is rational. and 0 is rational. So it means the circle passes (p,q) where p,q are rational.

Comment: @dice Your notion of "passes the rational points" is still not clear.  The circle is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and it's a proper subset so it can't possibly contain all ordered pairs of rationals.  It might be useful to introduce the set $Q = \{(p,q) \in S^1 \; | \; p,q \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ so we know what you're referring to.

Comment: Hint: Reduce the problem to which **integers** are representable as the sum of two squares.

Comment: Is this right? Suppose $x=\frac{x}{m},$ $y=\frac{y}{m}$ then by multiplying $m^{2}$.
We have $x^{2}+y^{2}=(rm)^{2}$. We need $(x,y,rm)$ to be Pythagorian
triples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{Q}{\mathbb{Q}}$
Depending on what you mean by "passes the rational points"...

Any circle with a rational radius $r \in \Q$ will **pass through** an infinite number of points with rational coordinates. For every Pythagorean triple $(a,b,c)$, the circle will pass through $(\frac{ra}{c},\frac{rb}{c})$ and its counterparts.

On the other hand, if you want a circle that will *avoid* (**pass by**) rational coordinate pairs, it is certainly enough to have a radius that is not an algebraic number, ie. is transcendental. However I suspect that the [*quadratic surds*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_irrational), solutions of $ax^2+bx+c=0$ with $a,b,c\in \Q, $ are the only additional non-rational values for the radius that allow the circle to pass through rational coordinate pairs.